# Javascript GetElementByName within a C# HtmlDocument

Tags: c#, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, webautomation

I am writing a web automation that fills out lengthy online forms based on stored data and then notifies the user of the results. The website that I am automating names all of it's objects, but does not use the id tag.  Is there something like HtmlDocument.GetElementById that works with the name tag?  I don't think GetElementsByTagName is right.  It doesn't return the specific element, but instead generates an array.

Comment: How does it "name" these objects? In terms of `DOM` a tag name is the element name (so for image elements, the tag name is `img`).

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="collectionSelectYear" value="2002" >  as opposed to <input type="hidden" id="collectionSelectYear" value="2002" >

Comment: the tag name for `GetElementsByTagName` is your example would be `input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements returned by `GetElementsByTagName` and check their `name` attribute (which is not the same as a tag name).

`GetElementByTagName` gets all elements that have the same element name (so for images, the tag name is `img`).

```
var inputs = GetElementsByTagName("input");

for(var input in inputs)
{
  if(input.GetAttribute("name") == nameIAmLookingFor)
  {
    // do something
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I voted up for Oded's answer as I do think Nathan meant "name" as attribute. One note, though. "_...var input.._" should only work with C# 3.0+ version.

Comment: The changes I am making are actually to broken code that I've inherited. I have an HtmlDocument, conWin that is created with wbSite.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.Window.Frames[0].Document; I am not getting any return values from this code now.  Do I need to adjust the HtmlDocument that I am analyzing for this to work?

Comment: @Nathan - Ouch. Nested frame within a nested frame :( Perhaps using the HTML Agility Pack to parse and query the HTML would be a better option.

Comment: Yeah, most of this code is pretty messy, and it doesn't help that the website that needs to be automated has been updated as well. Thank you for your comments though. I believe that will work once I clean up the rest of it.

Comment: I cannot get the website to actually give me the full HtmlDocument.  I've tried things as simple as wbSite.Document and it just yields a Windows error page that tells me I need a browser that supports frames. Is there a way to get the full web page that is actually displayed in the browser control without specifying which frames to grab?